# Python interface supported link speed

Tags: python, networking

What is the preferred and cross-platform (Ubuntu, Redhat) way to get supported interface link speed?

i am familiar with ethtool, but i would like an option not to use an external tool, but only python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually a python module providing bindings for the ethtool kernel interface. This sound like what you're looking for. See https://github.com/fedora-python/python-ethtool for details.

Comment: I'm able to get IP addresses etc. using the module, but I can't find a way to get the link status (link detected), speed, duplex and if auto-negotiation is enabled. Could you provide an example for that?

Comment: I have also checked the `pethtool` and didn't find a way to check the link speed using this library in `Python`.

Comment: This answer is marked as "accepted", but it doesn't appear that the Python `ethtool` module actually does what gtfx was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Until something better is invented you can use this on Linux:

```
with open(f'/sys/class/net/<iface-name>/speed') as f:
    iface_speed_mbps = int(f.read().strip())
```

However, it seems [not always](https://serverfault.com/questions/207474/how-do-i-verify-the-speed-of-my-nic) available.